TRIAC Blows Off in Single-Phase Induction Motor Capacitor Switching Circuit

(Q2 is not populated)in above circuit the R11, R12 VALUE IS 360 ohm 2W, R10 is 39 ohm 2W and the c2 is 0.01uf 1000v fuse is rated 16A 250V, Q1 is BTA41600B, the above circuit use 80-100UF 250vac starting capacitor add through j2 terminal and other pin of j2 connected to aux of motor and 30uF running capacitor already placed in motor. The motor is 0.5HP, i have set time using Op-Amp that turn on triac for 3 second while the circuit on,in this duration starting capacitor add on auxiliary winding after three second Op-Amp turn of triac and capacitor disconnect.
I am working on a circuit involving a single-phase induction motor that uses a starting capacitor. The capacitor is supposed to be connected during the motor startup and then disconnected once the motor reaches a certain speed. However, I am facing an issue where the TRIAC blows off when trying to perform this operation.
Circuit Details:
Motor Type: Single-phase induction motor
Capacitor Configuration: Starting capacitor connected and disconnected for motor start operation
Components Involved:
TRIAC: BTA41600B
Optocoupler: MOC3061
Gate Resistance: Approximately 360 ohms
Snubber Circuit: 39 ohm resistor and 0.01uF 1000V capacitor
Problem:
The TRIAC blows off when the starting capacitor should disconnect from the circuit. The issue seems to be related to the transient behavior during the switching process.
Observations:
The problem occurs specifically during the transition phase of the capacitor disconnection.
The motor runs fine initially but once the TRIAC attempts to disconnect the capacitor, it fails.
Questions:

What could be causing the TRIAC to blow off in this scenario?
Are there any specific protections or snubber circuits I should consider to handle the transients caused by disconnecting the starting capacitor?
Could there be any issues related to the timing of the TRIAC switching that I should investigate?
Are there any recommended practices for designing such circuits to ensure reliable operation?

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.



Please show component values on your schematic.   2. What are the motor parameters & ratings, ie: power rating, power factor at full load, full load current rating, start capacitor value, start winding inductance value.  3. What switches the capacitor out, a centrifugal (speed-triggered) switch?


Does this post address your situation?  Note that the motor winding data (inductance, resistance) must be obtained in order to design suitable protection for the TRIAC.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/69840/341959

KAMAL ZINZUVADIYA - (a) I edited the original question (which seems to have been copied & pasted from another place) since it lost some relevant formatting and was difficult to read - several sections ran together instead of being separated. However I did not understand some parts of the new details you added (and which you just moved in an edit) so I couldn't improve the readability there. (b) In English, you don't mean "blow off" for what the TRIAC does. Do you mean "blows up" or even "explodes"? Or do you just mean it fails, without any sound? Or something else? TY
